# Why is “h” used for height?

Tags: mathematics, notation

In Mathematics, it is common to use $h$ for height in various languages, including those whose word for height does not start with h. Why is that?

Comment: A cursive search shows that, in German and French, it's been in use since at least [1904](http://www.zeno.org/Lueger-1904/A/Mathematische+Zeichen) ([facsimile](http://www.zeno.org/Lueger-1904/K/lueger-1904-061-0335)) and [1843](https://archive.org/stream/annalesdestrava19publgoog/annalesdestrava19publgoog_djvu.txt) ([facsimile](https://archive.org/details/annalesdestrava19publgoog/page/240/mode/2up)), respectively (probably much longer). Also in Portuguese it's a very common notation, besides arguably  [old Greek](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BD%95%CF%88%CE%BF%CF%82): ῠ̔́ψος • (húpsos).

Comment: Because notations are commonly imported from literature in the language dominant in the field at the time and then retained. Historically, it was Greek and Latin first, later French, German and English. When a prominent author uses a letter from non-native alphabet (like Cantor used Hebrew א), that too is retained. Height is not unique, and this is not specific to mathematics, $m$ for mass, $E$ for energy, etc., are used in physics across the board.

Comment: "Because notations are commonly imported from literature in the language dominant in the field at the time and then retained". For $h$ we have hauteur (French), Höhe (German), height (English).

Comment: @njuffa, thank you very much for commenting. Though I believe you are right, French and German were dominant for a small time compared to Latin, so knowing when $h$ started to be used for height is essential to know if you're right. I may be wrong, but I think it is a weirdly hard question to answer — I am probably wrong.

Comment: @Schilive "so knowing when $h$ started to be used for height is essential to know" What does your own research show in regard to this question? I would suggest adding that information to the question.

Comment: I'd think it's a bit more complicated. Letters are often inspired by language words, but don't necessarily have to. They also shouldn't clash with other conventions; e.g. using $a$ for height (from Latin altitudo) could be confused with acceleration in physics, or the maths convention to use $a$, $b$, $c$,.. for constants in polynomials or for the sides of triangles in geometry. Which symbol to use is a conventions that is not as strictly defined as other mathematical symbols. For example, it's not uncommon to use $z$ for the height (as vertical coordinate) in physics.